# Script with zip command doesn't work with wildcards

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, scripting, zip

I created a bash shell script to zip  all files that match a pattern as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
zip $1 $2
```

When I run the above script using `./myScript.sh myzip test*`, only one file that starts with the name *test* is added to the zip even though my directory has 2 files (test1 and test2) that match the pattern.

If I run the `zip` command directly from the shell, it works as expected and adds both *test1* and *test2* to myzip. But when I use a script to do this, it adds only 1 file.

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 4):

When you call your script like

```
./myScript.sh myzip test*
```

you give the script the arguments `myzip`, `test1` and `test2`. The last two arguments are expanded from the `test*` pattern by the shell before the script is actually invoked.  Note that `test2` will be available in `$3`, but your script never uses `$3`.

You can solve this in two ways:

1. Pick off the archive name from the argument list, then shift the list to remove the archive name from the list of positional parameters, and finally use `"$@"` (the remaining arguments) in the call to `zip`:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   archive=$1
   shift

   zip "$archive" "$@"
   ```

   Since all variables are quoted, this additionally means that you'd be able to work with filenames that contain whitespace etc.

   With `bash`, this could possibly be written a bit more unreadably as

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   zip "$1" "${@:2}"
   ```
2. The `zip` utility knows how to expand shell globbing patterns itself. Use this fact to give the script a *pattern* rather than a list of filenames:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   zip "$1" "$2"
   ```

   This script should be called as

   ```
   ./myScript.sh myzip 'test*'
   ```

   The quoting of `test*` stops the shell from expanding the pattern (which is what we *rely on* in the first alternative).

Comment: Always quote variable(unless there is a good reason not to: you want that behaviour), if they need them or not: so `archive="$1"` not `archive=$1`. There is no point carrying around in our heads a list of edge cases.

Comment: Note the 1st example is able to be called in both ways (`test*` and `'test*'`) . It is therefore more robust.